# Using a UDF multiple times in a Sproc

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2005, user-defined-functions

I have a SQL 2k5 sproc I'm working with.

I need to reference a UDF to calculate price based on a few variables and the users permissions.   I originally tried this, but it didn't work because I wasn't referencing a field...

```
SELECT dbo.f_GetPrice(model,userid,authType) 'YourPrice', name, description 
FROM tblRL_Products
WHERE 'YourPrice' Between @fromPrice AND @toPrice
     OR 'YourPrice' IS NULL
```

So I modified this to

```
SELECT dbo.f_GetPrice(model,userid,authType) 'YourPrice', name, description 
FROM tblRL_Products
WHERE dbo.f_GetPrice(model,userid,authType) Between @fromPrice AND @toPrice
     OR dbo.f_GetPrice(model,userid,authType) IS NULL
```

When SQL executes this sproc, is it running the function 3X's for each record or does it run it the one time and use the values in the other two places per row.

Is there a more efficient way of doing this?

---

**Edit**

This is the Scalar UDF.  It needs to grab a price based on the type the user is authorized for, then once we have the right price we need to do a calculation on it.  This is all stored in the authorization tables.  Every user has an authorization for each line of products.  So they may have different price types and calculations for each line, returning back dozens or even hundreds of lines in a single search result call.

In the above code I used authType, that was an old call, we don't use that parameter anymore.

```
ALTER function [dbo].[f_GetPrice]
(
    @model uniqueidentifier,
    @userID uniqueidentifier    
)
returns money
as
begin

Declare @yourPrice money

WITH ProductPrice AS(
SELECT (CASE PriceType
        WHEN 'msrp' THEN p.price_msrp
            WHEN 'jobber' THEN p.price_jobber
            WHEN 'warehouse' THEN p.price_warehouse
            WHEN 'margin' THEN p.price_margin
            WHEN 'mycost' THEN p.price_mycost
            WHEN 'customprice1' THEN p.price_custom1
            WHEN 'customprice2' THEN p.price_custom2
            WHEN 'customprice3' THEN p.price_custom2
            ELSE p.price_msrp
        END) as YourPrice, aup.calc, aup.amount
FROM products p 
    JOIN lines l ON l.lineID=l.lineID
    JOIN authorizations a ON l.authlineID=a.authlineID
    JOIN authorizationusers au ON a.auID=au.auID
    JOIN authorizationuserprices aup ON au.aupID=aup.aupID
WHERE au.userID=@userID AND p.modelID=@model)


SELECT @yourPrice=(CASE calc
            WHEN 'amount' THEN YourPrice+amount
            WHEN 'percent' THEN YourPrice+(YourPrice*amount/100)
            WHEN 'divide' THEN YourPrice/amount
            WHEN 'factore' THEN YourPrice*amount
            WHEN 'none' THEN YourPrice
            ELSE YourPrice
           END) FROM ProductPrice

return @yourPrice

END
```

Comment: better yet, please show the code of `dbo.f_GetPrice` and we can help you make it ***really*** good

Answer (score 5):

If you must use a udf for this, then use a subquery and filter outside the subquery:

```
select YourPrice, name, description
from
(
  SELECT dbo.f_GetPrice(model,userid,authType) YourPrice, name, description 
  FROM tblRL_Products
) d
WHERE YourPrice Between @fromPrice AND @toPrice
     OR YourPrice IS NULL
```

Then you are only calling your udf once instead of 3 times.

Comment: I simplified a complex sproc to show the problem without a bunch of extra stuff.  I'm already using this in a subquery to do paging.  I thought about doing this but my fear was that I would be bringing back a bunch of records in many cases when I am only really returning a few.  So I would grab all the records fitting the other critiera just to later pare it down to the dozen I needed outside the subquery.  That seemed like it would take longer than filtering up front.  That's why I didn't do that.

Answer (score 0):

Scalar functions are not good, when they have to be applied to a quite number of rows. In this case definitely you can convert your scalar function into table-valued function, which will not be called one time for every row of input data.

```
create function [dbo].[ft_GetPrice]
(
    @model uniqueidentifier,
    @userID uniqueidentifier    
)
returns table
as return
(
    WITH ProductPrice AS (
        SELECT (CASE PriceType
                WHEN 'msrp' THEN p.price_msrp
                    WHEN 'jobber' THEN p.price_jobber
                    WHEN 'warehouse' THEN p.price_warehouse
                    WHEN 'margin' THEN p.price_margin
                    WHEN 'mycost' THEN p.price_mycost
                    WHEN 'customprice1' THEN p.price_custom1
                    WHEN 'customprice2' THEN p.price_custom2
                    WHEN 'customprice3' THEN p.price_custom2
                    ELSE p.price_msrp
                END) as YourPrice, aup.calc, aup.amount
        FROM products p 
            JOIN lines l ON l.lineID=l.lineID
            JOIN authorizations a ON l.authlineID=a.authlineID
            JOIN authorizationusers au ON a.auID=au.auID
            JOIN authorizationuserprices aup ON au.aupID=aup.aupID
        WHERE au.userID=@userID AND p.modelID=@model
    )
    SELECT
        CASE calc
            WHEN 'amount' THEN YourPrice+amount
            WHEN 'percent' THEN YourPrice+(YourPrice*amount/100)
            WHEN 'divide' THEN YourPrice/amount
            WHEN 'factore' THEN YourPrice*amount
            WHEN 'none' THEN YourPrice
            ELSE YourPrice
        END as YourPrice
    FROM ProductPrice
)
GO
```

Which can be used then as:

```
SELECT fp.YourPrice, name, description
FROM tblRL_Products
    outer apply dbo.ft_GetPrice(model, userid, authType) fp
WHERE fp.YourPrice Between @fromPrice AND @toPrice OR fp.YourPrice IS NULL
```

Comment: I'm going to test this now.  So creating a table value function is faster than a scalar.  It still has to be run for every row.  What is it that makes scalars so much worse on large return sets as opposed to table values when they are both doing almost the same thing for each row?  Definitely trying this but just curious about the obvious misunderstanding I have about scalar UDFs.

Comment: @IshmaelStruan, Yes, table function is also doing calculation for every row of input data, but in contrast to scalar function inline table-valued function will do it for all input rows at once as a set operation. Just like if you would executed a query `select ... from tblRL_Products join products p on ... join authorizationusers ... etc.` In case of scalar function, a call should happen, then result should be calculated, and then return from call should happen also. Even a tiny overhead of 1msec to call/return for a row could result to 10 sec. overhead on a relatively small 10k rows set.